@capawesome/capacitor-app-update responses "Required app information could not be fetched"
In capacitor app, I would like to use @capawesome/capacitor-app-update plugin to fetch app information including current version, etc.
However methods that I tried (getAppUpdateInfo() and openAppStore()) response error message which is below.

[error] - {"errorMessage":"Required app information could not be fetched"}

I looked it up with this error message but helpful information didn't come up.
Does anyone know solutions and causes?
Thank you in advance.

This error message appears if your app is not available in some countries. Make sure you set the country option:
import { AppUpdate } from '@capawesome/capacitor-app-update';

const getAppUpdateInfo = async () => {
  const result = await AppUpdate.getAppUpdateInfo({ country: '...' });
  console.log(result);
};


It doesn't work and the same error message is came up but I didn't realize this option is needed. thank you for information :-)
